# No wireless networks on boot, works after suspending

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, suspend, realtek

Having a curious issue with wireless networking on my wife's Ubuntu 20.04 HP laptop. After installing a few months worth of updates today (this laptop is infrequently used) I find that the wifi does not connect automatically after starting up. Checking the wifi tray menu, I see there are no networks available. By chance I happened to find however that if suspend the system and bring it back, the wireless works and happily connects by itself.

The chipset is a Realtek one, using the RTL8188EE driver, in case that matters. Also, this system was previously upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and there were previous wifi issues, whose resolution sadly I am unable to remember at this point.

Anyway, since it works after suspending I imagine the chip and driver are probably okay and I'm just missing something in the boot scripts. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many times did you boot to show that it's a consistent boot issue? I have a laptop that fails to connect to the network on about 10% wake-ups (not boots), never been able to localize a specific cause; just 20 seconds to sleep-and-wake-up-again to get function.

Comment: Three out of three so far. I do think maybe the last time I had this, it just worked after a given number of reboots, as strange as that sounds. Not happened yet this time around though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This system no longer exists so there will presumably never be an answer to it. I will mark as resolved; if it should be deleted instead perhaps someone can let me know.